# PRIME is not working on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, optimus

- xrandr --listproviders

> Providers: number : 2
> Provider 0: id: 0x46 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 4 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
> Provider 1: id: 0xb4 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 2 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting

here it looks like everything is order. my system recognizes my two different cards.

- prime-run glxinfo

> name of display: :0
> X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
> Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
> Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
> Value in failed request:  0x0
> Serial number of failed request:  39
> Current serial number in output stream:  40

and here is the error output when i try to run my dedicated graphics card.

I did everything in the wiki said in order:

- I installed nouveau drivers
- I set the offloading and created `xorg.conf` file in `/etc/X11`.

I did them correctly but still it's not working.

Comment: Please post text ***as text*** and not as screenshots,  and describe what you are trying to do, and what is happening, in sentences.